# Pymongo $sort parameters order

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting

I have a sort like this:

```
db.getCollection('TEST').aggregate([
    {'$sort': {'create_time': 1, 'status': 1}}
])
```

It has 2 sort fields, mongo will sort the `create_time` field first, then `status`.But in python `dict` is disordered, it sometimes sorts `create_time` first, sometimes `status` first, so the question is how can I make sure it always sorts the `create_time` first?

Comment: Use `sort` function which accepts a `tuple`. `collection.find().sort([("date",pymongo.DESCENDING), ("another_date",pymongo.DESCENDING)])`

Comment: Hi Garbage Collector, cause I have other options (such as `$addFields` and sort by the added field), so I must use `aggregate` to do this.

Comment: Then have a look at [Ordered Dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: I have tried by this and it works.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go by a sort instead of `aggregate`

This is the pattern:

```
.sort([("field1", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("field2", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

You can chain the functions so that you can limit the documents to sort by a filter first:

```
db.getCollection('TEST').find({ field1: <value>, field2: <value> ... }).sort([("field3", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("field4", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

As a side note: the fields in .find() and .sort() do not need to be different.